# Event not triggering in Marionette Itemview

Tags: events, triggers, marionette

I am trying to trigger an event in the marionette itemview (List.SendQuestion), however, I was unable to register the trigger in the controller (as seen below)

Essentially, after clicking on the 'a.send', a trigger was supposed to happen and the 'send_qn_view' should capture the event and print out the message 'triggered'. But that was not happening.

Can someone advise me what might be going wrong here?

```
@Dailymuses.module "SidebarModule.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  List.Controller = 
    showSidebar: ->
      send_qn_view = new List.SendQuestions
        collection: Onethingaday.Public.friends

      send_qn_view.on "itemview:ask:user", (itemview, question) ->
        console.log('triggered') #THIS IS NOT EXECUTED

  class List.SendQuestion extends Marionette.ItemView
    template: "sidebar/list/templates/send_question"
    className: 'qn_askee'
    tagName: 'li'

    events:
      "click a.send" : "sendQuestion"

    sendQuestion: (e) ->
      e.preventDefault()
      debugger #this debugger was triggered
      @trigger "ask:user", @model

  class List.SendQuestions extends Marionette.CompositeView
    template: "sidebar/list/templates/send_questions"
    itemView: List.SendQuestion
    itemViewContainer: "ul.friends"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Edit: Corrected my answer and updated my fiddle*

Sorry about that.  Your syntax for event bubbling is correct.
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#childview-event-bubbling-from-child-views

> "itemview:*" event bubbling from child views
>
> When an item view within a collection view triggers an event, that
>   event will bubble up through the parent collection view with
>   "itemview:" prepended to the event name.
>
> That is, if a child view triggers "do:something", the parent
>   collection view will then trigger "itemview:do:something".

Something to note.  Marionette supports view triggers.  If your callback is just triggering a view event you can remove the event hash and callback and shorten your code to this:

```
triggers: {
  "click a.send": "ask:user"
}
```

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/05/15/workflow-in-backbone-apps-triggering-view-events-from-dom-events/

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/FRHkt/1/

Comment: One more question, how do I add a model as a parameter during the trigger?

Comment: Sorry actually I realize that in your fiddle, the trigger event was placed in the collection view. In my original post, the issue I faced was actually having a trigger event in the 'itemView' i.e. in your var PatchView. How can I trigger the event from the itemView instead?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone new coming to this example, with Marionette 2.x, `itemview:*` for children views have been replaced with `childview:` triggers in the parent view, and the collection and composite views have also had their parameters changed from `itemView` and `itemViewContainer` to `childView` and `childViewContainer`