# Marionette ItemView not emitting "change" events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

## The Problem

I'm following a tutorial on how to make single page apps using Marionette/Backbone and currently it's describing how to pass around information about the current user. The current user is stored in a variable connected to the global App and is currently being rendered as part of the footer template. The problem is that when the current user is updated the corresponding ItemView is not also updated.

On application start the current user is turned into a valid Backbone model (using information from data bootstrapped using gon) and renders correctly in the footer. However, when the **full_name** attribute is updated from the console (using *Demo.currentUser.set({full_name: "John Smith"})* ) there is no change in the footer.

## What I've tried

I believe I've correctly implemented linking the change event to the render function, as described in the tutorial and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876970/marionette-itemview-how-to-re-render-model-on-change).

I've tried also updating the model to a different user in case the **set** method doesn't fire the **change** event, but that also had no effect. Additionally, I did try implementing some logging, as below, to detect whether the **change** event was being fired or not and it appears not to be fired.

I've searched for people answering similar problems, however, some of the questions appear to refer to problems like [ItemViews in CollectionViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662421/marionette-itemview-not-rendering) or more complicated [events being fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313946/event-not-triggering-in-marionette-itemview). I've also looked at the Marionette and Backbone docs to try and find out what exactly triggers the **change** event, but was unable to find out. Therefore, I'm now a bit stuck.

Any help on this problem would be hugely appreciated.

## Code

The FooterApp Show controller (I've also exposed the currentUser variable and checked whether the model is being updated correctly and it is):

```
@Demo.module "FooterApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) -> 

    Show.Controller = 
    
        showFooter: ->
            currentUser = Backbone.Radio.request "global", "get:current:user"
            footerView = @getFooterView currentUser 
            App.footerRegion.show footerView 
         
        getFooterView: (currentUser) -> 
            new Show.Footer 
               model: currentUser
```

The FooterApp Show view (the commented out bits show the logging attempt):

```
@Demo.module "FooterApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

    class Show.Footer extends Marionette.ItemView
        template: "footer/show/templates/show_footer"
    
        modelEvents:
           "change" : "render" # "change" : "onChange"

        #  onChange: ->
        #    console.log "Model changed"
        #    render
```

The view template:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted">BackboneRails - Episode 5 Creation - Current User: <%= @full_name%></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

App.js.coffee, to show where the currentUser is stored and retrieved from:

```
@Demo = do (Backbone, Marionette) ->

    Backbone.Radio.DEBUG = true
    # Backbone.Radio.tuneIn "global"

    App = new Marionette.Application

    App.on "before:start", (options) ->
        @currentUser = Backbone.Radio.request "global", "set:current:user", options.currentUser

    Backbone.Radio.reply "global", "get:current:user", ->
        App.currentUser

    App.addRegions
        headerRegion: "#header-region"
        mainRegion: "#main-region"
        footerRegion: "#footer-region"

    App.addInitializer ->
        App.module("FooterApp").start()
        App.module("HeaderApp").start()

    App.on "start", ->
        if Backbone.history
           Backbone.history.start()
  
    App
```

EDIT: Thanks for all your help (and sorry about the slow reply - I've been moving house, which has been a bit hectic). It's now working and I'm pretty sure it was a formatting problem with my coffeescript (that wasn't visible in the formatting of the question). I added the logging code above the link between **change** and **render** and it started working. Using **git diff**, the only difference appears to be some indentation, which I think would have changed the javascript that was generated.

Comment: I walked through you code, read a bit about `Backbone.Radio` . You could make a fiddle for this issue and we could look at it there. I guess issue comes from `Backbone.Events` and `Backbone.Radio` mix.

Comment: I have tried making the Show controller obtain the current user model directly from App.currentUser and it still seems exhibit similar behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

I basically always like to take this approach to debugging events not firing or not working as I expect:

Can you try doing a

```
events: {
  "all": "log"
}

log: function(e) {
  console.log e;
}
```

That should log out every event that's getting fired. I find it super helpful when troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Please post all of your code. A guess I would make without seeing all of your code is that you work with more than one currentUser instance, so the change event is emitted on a different user model than the one passed into the view.

By the way - Backbones and Marionettes code is very accessible. Don't be afraid of it - read it and debug trough it.